# Unable to access object variable from bound function, or internal method from unbound function

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

Just for reference, I'm trying to follow the [Abstract Encoding](https://github.com/mafintosh/abstract-encoding) specifications. Essentially, I want to create a "function variable" `let foo = codec.encode`, where `encode()` calls another function within `codec`, and I can access `foo.bytes`. It seems I can either access the value of `bytes` but not be able to access the inner function `this.encodingLength()`, or create a bound function variable and have the exact opposite occur. This issue only occurs when I assign the function `encode()` to a variable. I read somewhere that `bind()` creates a wrapper function (which wouldn't be able to access `bytes`, and also that the object functions cannot access other object functions if it doesn't have the correct context. Is it possible to have both worlds?

Example Code:

```
const codec = {
  encode: function encode () {
    encode.bytes = 2
    this.encodingLength()
  },
  encodingLength: function encodingLength () { }
}

let foo = codec.encode
let bar = codec.encode.bind(codec)

> foo()
TypeError: this.encodingLength is not a function
    at encode (repl:4:6)
> foo.bytes
2

> bar()
undefined
> bar.bytes
undefined
```

Also using `this.encode.bytes` seems to make no difference

```
const codec = {
  encode () {
    this.encode.bytes = 2
    this.encodingLength()
  },
  encodingLength () { }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the `bytes` to be (potentially) different for every call of `encode`?

Comment: Yes (it should be), although for demonstration purposes I just assigned it to `2`

Comment: Just for reference, specifying a global variable for returning values from calls is a *horrible* thing.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The "*Abstract Encoding*" spec you linked says "*After encoding `encoding.encode.bytes` should be set to the amount of bytes used to encode the object.*". `encoding.encode.bytes` is essentially a global variable, unless they assume that every encoding is instantiated as a single-use object with non-shared methods. And using globals for passing return values is a horrible idea - which also causes your problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's certainly not the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```js
// define encodingLength function here
function encodingLength(object) {
  // determine encoding length of obj here
  return 5; // dummy value
}

const codec = {
  encode: function encode(object, buffer, offset) {
    // encode object here
    // capture `encodingLength` in a closure
    encode.bytes = encodingLength(object); // dummy value
    return []; // dummy empty "buffer"
  },
  decode: function decode(buffer, start, end) {
    // decode buffer here
    decode.bytes = 12; // another dummy value
    return {}; // dummy "decoded" object
  },
  encodingLength: encodingLength
};

let foo = codec.encode;
foo();
console.log(foo.bytes); // 5, as expected
console.log(codec.encode.bytes); // 5, as expected

let bar = codec.decode;
bar();
console.log(bar.bytes); // 12, as expected
console.log(codec.decode.bytes); // 12, as expected
```

Comment: Thanks! Although again `bar.bytes` returns `undefined`. Additionally, `codec.encode(); codec.encode.bytes` also returns `undefined` (which it shouldn't according to the [Abstract Encoding Spec](https://github.com/mafintosh/abstract-encoding)), so unfortunately not

Comment: @marceloneil I've updated my answer, please take a second look.

Comment: Thanks again! I've tried this before, although I have multiple codecs per file (each require an `encodingLength()`. If this is the only option I'll either have to create a file per codec, or rename the defined `encodingLength()` function to something like `codecEncodingLength()`

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and just don't use `this`:

```
const codec = {
  encode() {
    codec.encode.bytes = 2;
    codec.encodingLength();
//  ^^^^^
  },
  encodingLength() {},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
const Codec = (function() {
    let bytes = 2;
    return {
        encode,
        encodingLength
    };

    function encode() {
        bytes++;
        encodingLength();
    }

    function encodingLength() {
        console.log(`bytes: ${bytes}`);
    }
});

const foo = new Codec();
foo.encode(); // output: bytes: 3

const bar = new Codec();
bar.encode(); // output: bytes: 3
```